# How to install Apparmor profile on Ubuntu 14.04 for sendmail?

Tags: ubuntu, sendmail, apparmor

I am running sendmail on ubuntu 14.04 together with OpenEmm. The man page of OpenEmm claims that I have to add some lines to the Apparmor profile if it is active.

Unfortunately there is no sendmail profile available, therefore I tried to install the corresponding profile.

```
 sudo apt-get install apparmor-profiles
```

The profile is located here:

```
/usr/share/doc/apparmor-profiles/extras/usr.sbin.sendmail
```

My question is, how to install this profile? Is it enough just to move it to /etc/apparmor.d/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Have to tried this after moving it to /etc/apparmor.d/ ? :

```
aa-enforce /etc/apparmor.d/* #To launch all the profiles
aa-enforce sendmail #if you have created your sendmail profile
```

I guess that those commands are provided by the apparmor-utils package